# SIGINT error WRF

Tags: atmosphere-modelling, wrf

I am trying to run WRF 3.8.1 using ncep2 but after a while the run stops and I get following error:

```
rsl.error.0211:forrtl: error (69): process interrupted (SIGINT)
rsl.error.0212:forrtl: error (69): process interrupted (SIGINT)
rsl.error.0213:forrtl: error (69): process interrupted (SIGINT)
```

I tried setting following in by `.bashrc` file:

```
ulimit-n -s unlimited
export OMP_STACKSIZE=64m
```

but the problem still is there and nothing improved. Any suggestions please? Thank you!

Comment: Can you post a link to a full `rsl.error.0000` and `rsl.error.0211`?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/33i6yio1h9xx8w2/rsl.error.0213?dl=0

Comment: `rsl.error.0213` does not contain helpful information about the interruption. How about `rsl.error.0000`?

Comment: @gansub yes i did send mail to wrfhelp, no reply yet. i did compile it using intel compiler

Comment: @saurabh - from those messages i guessed you were using intel compiler. you need to take this question to intel compiler forum and post it over there. they can help you debug it.

Comment: @saurabh - https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/determining-root-cause-of-sigsegv-or-sigbus-errors. So you can do one of two things. Recompile with gfortran and see if you reproduce this error. Then you know it is due to ifort alone. If yes then ask Intel fortran support to help you out

Comment: The consensus at https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77/would-geosciences-specific-software-support-be-on-topic-here is that support for geoscience-specific software - which the WRF model indisputably is - is on-topic. Therefore, voting to leave open as this is not off-topic.

Comment: Are you using a job scheduler? I see SIGINT coming from the scheduler sometimes when it decides to take down a job, for instance if time allotment has expired.